# how to adding tri-state checkbox in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

i want to make a tri-state checkbox inside listview control, iam using image list for listview items, so i cant make a three images for the checkbox. is there any custom listview control or any way to do tri-state checkbox?

thanks for helping

Comment: I don't know, but the third state is called something like intermediate if I'm right. Maybe this helps you a little bit further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView

Comment: thanks very much, can i put a checkbox in the column header of the objectlistbox?

Comment: if your wanting to do that I would suggest doing it in WPF its going to be alot easier